# What is Global Avalanche Criteria(GAC)

Tags: s-boxes

[GAC](http://www.jucs.org/jucs_1_5/gac_the_criterion_for/Zhang_X.pdf) consists of absolute indicator and sum of square indicator. Please help me in understanding what are these indicators? How to calculate GAC for Sbox?
What is confusion Coefficient Variance of an Sbox?

Comment: It is my remembrance that GA refers to "Guaranteed Avalanche". confusion Coefficient Variance ? never heard of it

Comment: i have linked the paper, you can check it